# Is there a way to hit 2 Oracle linked servers in SQL Server query using EXEC AT?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, linked-server

I am working on a SQL Server query where I need to access tables from 2 Oracle linked servers. Something like a query with joins to tables coming from 2 different Oracle linked servers.

I was able to do this using `openquery`, but the dreaded 8000 character string limit makes the new query I am working on not achievable. Well, I guess it can work but will be very very hard to follow the query later.

Comment: Are you passing long value list inside `IN (...)`?

Comment: Hi,  No.  The query is just complex.

Comment: Can you convert that query to a proc on Oracle and use RPC?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We are in a middle of some experimentation.  We wanted to make a MSSQL server with linked servers to several Oracle databases as a some sort of data point.  So, that idea was to go through the MSSQL server for all data needs.  We are looking for a way to execute a query with tables joined from different databases